# Strategy Stop or Halt syntax in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

Is there any specific syntax for stopping or halting the strategy after specific condition?
I know it is possible with few manually conditions but I'm looking forward for built-in syntax if exist.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
strategy.close("entryNameHere", when = yourBoolCondition)
```

Cheers and best of luck

Comment: This comment only close current positions, I need command to stop the strategy and no new order can open after that.

Comment: You would couple your halt condition with your entry condition. Example: long = longCondition and not haltCondition

Comment: Still not my answer. Please read the question carefully before your answer

Comment: " I know it is possible with few manually conditions but I'm looking forward for built-in syntax if exist"

Comment: Built in syntax? Read carefully. You create your own conditions. You can use "not" to ensure something doesn't happen when you want.